# pam_unix error when attempting to setup rdxp with AD integration

Tags: pam, session, active-directory, sssd, xrdp

Issue: Installed Realm, SSSD and SSH works with all users, but trying to remote desktop using xrdp fails with the following errors

```
Aug 30 00:00:00 PC-NAME xrdp-sesman[220997]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=xrdp-sesman ruser= rhost=  user=username
Aug 30 00:00:00 PC-NAME xrdp-sesman[220997]: pam_sss(xrdp-sesman:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=xrdp-sesman ruser= rhost= user=username
Aug 30 00:00:00 PC-NAME xrdp-sesman[222108]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
Aug 30 00:00:00 PC-NAME xrdp-sesman[222108]: pam_systemd(xrdp-sesman:session): Failed to create session: No such process
Aug 30 00:00:00 PC-NAME xrdp-sesman[222108]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session closed for user username
```

Configuration for /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
domains = SOME.DOMAIN
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/SOME.DOMAIN]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = SOME.DOMAIN
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
#realmd_tags = joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = SOME.DOMAIN
use_fully_qualified_names = False
#simple_allow_users = $
ldap_id_mapping = True
#access_provider = ad
access_provider = simple

# Fixes for long load times.
# case_sensitive = False
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
# ad_gpo_map_remote_interactive = +xrdp-sesman
ignore_group_members = true
ldap_refferals = false
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Similar issues for reference (Resolved but resolution doesn't work for me):

- https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1684
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150283/ubuntu-16-active-directory-can-ssh-cannot-rdp

What have I tried

- changing gpo to permissive: "ad_gpo_access_control = permissive"
- edit "/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config" to "allowed_users=anybody"
- changed "access_provider = simple" from "access_provider = ad"

Comment: "Same issue as the following" is not OK; please expand your answer by explaining from zero your problem; links to similar/connected issues are welcome as well but you have to develop your issue here, first